# Ir para âncora antes do carregamento completo da página

Tags: jquery, html

Possuo uma página que toda vez ao atualizar, retorna ao topo após o carregamento completo. Porém, possuo uma segunda página que tem um *link* da seguinte forma: `index.html#empresa`, gostaria que a mesma parasse,"independentemente" do seu carregamento, na âncora **empresa**.

→ [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/EJMNh9zi) do `index.html`

Comment: Sugiro colocar parte do código aqui dentro do stackoverflow ou então usar a opção snippet.

Comment: Sua duvida é "Como navegar pra uma ancora dentro da página com javascript?"

Comment: @LeonanCarvalho, não. Necessito que ao carregar o  link `index.html#empresa`, o mesmo pare na âncora **empresa** e não no topo da página. Pois, o parametro #empresa via URL, simplesmente está sendo "desconsiderado" pela chamada de carregamento completo da página: `$(document).ready(function(e) {});`, porém não sei se é realmente isso e como está ocorrendo esse problema.

Comment: @LeonanCarvalho, o arquivo `index.html` excede o limite de caracteres permitido para publicação.

Comment: Se você navegasse para ancora no on-load da página?

Comment: Podemos ir para o [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64546/ir-para-ancora-antes-do-carregamento-completo-da-pagina)? @LeonanCarvalho

Comment: Não vi o indicador no código da sua pagina

Comment: Não vi o indicador no código da sua pagina. Veja esse exemplo  
 http://kithomepage.com/kit/tutorial/html/hiperlinks.php#indicador

Answer (score 0):

O código abaixo deve funcionar ao seu propósito:

```
<script>
    curr_url = window.location.href; //pego a URL da página
    if(curr_url.indexOf("#") != -1){ // verifico se existe # na URL
       parametro = curr_url.substring(curr_url.indexOf("#"),curr_url.length); // extraio da URL a string com tudo que vier depois de "#" (inclusive o "#")
       $('html, body').animate({
           scrollTop: $(parametro).offset().top
       }, 10); // desço a janela até a div com o id extraido da string na URL
    }
</script>
```

Você pode usar o código sem esperar o carregamento da página (`$(document).ready`). Porém é preciso que o código esteja no final do `<body>`. Isso porque a página é carregada linha por linha, de cima para baixo e o elemento em questão (#empresa) já foi carregado.

> **Obs.:** Isso não funciona no *exatíssimo* momento em que a página é chamada. Vai
>   depender da velocidade do carregamento da página até chegar no script,
>   pois não é possível executar um script antes do carregamento normal da página.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).load(function(){
    if(window.location.hash) {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(window.location.hash).offset().top + 'px'
        }, 1000, 'swing');
    }
});
```